# Minimum of subset of vector (c++)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I need the index of the minimum value in a `vector<int>`, however only some indices must be taken into account. Say we have:

```
vector<int> distance({5, 5, 4, 3, 5});
vector<int> neighbors({0, 1, 2, 4});
```

Then the value 3 is not taken into account and thus 4 is the minimum value, hence I need index 2. One could solve it by adding a large constant to the values which are not taken into account:

```
int City::closest(set<int> const &neighbors) const
{
  vector<double> dist(d_distance);
  for (size_t idx = 0; idx != dist.size(); ++idx)
  {
    auto it = find(neighbors.begin(), neighbors.end(), idx);
    if (it == neighbors.end())
      dist[idx] = __INT_MAX__;
  }

  auto min_el = min_element(dist.begin(), dist.end());
  return distance(dist.begin(), min_el);
}
```

However I my opinion this method is unreadable and I would prefer a STL algorithm or a combination of two of them. Do you have a more neat solution for this?

Comment: Write unit tests. Do whatever it takes to make them pass. Do anything you like to make the code *cleaner* - while maintaining passing tests. ... And in case you have no framework nearby: A `main()` function is sufficient for unit testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the variant of `min_element` taking a comparator, and use `neighbors` as the range and `distance` as your cost function:

```
return *min_element(neighbors.begin(), neighbors.end(),
    [&](int i, int j) { return distance[i] < distance[j]; });
```

Comment: @RSahu yes, that's what's been asked for: "*I need the index of the minimum value in a `vector<int>`...*"

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I hoped for.

Comment: a small additional question, just from curiousity and not for optimization. Is it prefered to get the indices i and j by reference as in your solution? I thought that in general it is more expensive to create a reference than passing an int type, of course both are negligible.

Comment: @MichielUitHetBroek the `[&]` in the lambda is capturing `distance` by reference; `i` and `j` are passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do?

```
 int min=__INT_MAX__;
 int minIndex=-1;
 for(int i=0;i<neighbours.size();i++){

    if(distance[neighbours[i]]<min){
        min=distance[neighbours[i]];
        minIndex=i;
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't reinitializing min at every iteration lead to minIndex just being the size-1?